# How to create custom QML element from file in c++?

Tags: c++, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I have a custom QML element that I use in my app.

MyImageView.qml

I can create instances of it in javascript without issue using a ComponentDefinition such as (names and methods vastly simplified for sake of readability):

```
attachedObjects: [
    ComponentDefinition {
        id: defMyImageView
        MyImageView { }
    }
]

function addCustom() {
    var obj = defMyImageView.createObject();
    obj.customSource = "xyz";
    myContainer.add(obj);
}
```

How can I do the same using c++ while keeping the current MyImageView.qml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out after much searching and experimenting ;)

```
void ArticleParser::addImage(QString imageUrl, QString title) {
    QmlDocument *document = QmlDocument::create(
            "asset:///Articles/ArticleImage.qml"); //load qml file
    document->setParent(rootContainer); 

    if (!document->hasErrors()) {
        //Create Imageview
        Control *control = document->createRootObject<Control>();
        control->setProperty("source", imageUrl); //custom property
        control->setProperty("caption", title); //custom property

        rootContainer->add(control); //add control to my main container
    }
}
```

The above method is called from within c++ to add images using my custom image control (which supports http urls) so it can be added dynamically.